# How to run Robolectric with Flurry on Android

Tags: java, android, tdd, robolectric

When I try to run My robolectric tests, It throws a weird exception because of Flurry methods.

It is error that I came across.

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 17
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/flurry/android/FlurryAgent.init(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;)V @5: if_icmpge
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: b200 4f10 0aa2 000c b200 5012 06b8 007a
    0x0000010: b12a c700 0dbb 0044 5912 11b7 0089 bf2b
    0x0000020: c600 0a2b b600 8b9a 000d bb00 4159 1226
    0x0000030: b700 86bf b800 822a 2bb8 006e a700 0d4d
    0x0000040: b200 5012 012c b800 78b1               
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [52, 60] => handler: 63


    at com.pepapp.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:21)
    at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:140)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setUpApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:433)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:240)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

It is my MainApplication.java:21

```
FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled( true );
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to set up and run tests for static methods. Usually, people involve `PowerMock` to do that.

I would suggest you to wrap `Flurry` logging with your class.

**Pluses**

- You can swap/add analytics without touching app classes that use analytics
- You can unit test that your code fires analytics correctly

**Minuses**

- You need to write more code

You currently have the issue with unit testing your code.

So I would do it in next steps:

1. Create class `Analytics` that responsible for reporting
2. Implement proper dependency injection in app

You can also solve your problem it in short term:

1. Move call of the `Analytics` initialization into protected method of the app class:

   public class YourAppClassName {
       protected void initAnalytics(){
           FlurryAgant.setLogEnabled(true);
       }
   }
2. Add `Test<YourAppClassName>` into your test folder:

   public class Test{}
3. Override `Analytics` initialisation in test application:

   protected void initAnalytics(){}